# What is the value of "this" inside a function passed to __defineGetter__

Tags: javascript, scope, this, npm, anonymous-function

I am seeing following line of code from source code of grunt npm module -

```
String.prototype.__defineGetter__(method, function() { return this; });
```

Just trying to anticipate what will be the value of 'this' inside the anonymous function above -

- It points back to 'method'
- Global 'window' object if running in browser or something similar in grunt's perspective
- Something else depending on the definition of **defineGetter** if call or apply are used inside the 'defineGetter' definition.

Thanks for the help !!

Comment: Because `console.log()` is so 2011?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` will be the object on which the get operation occurs, which I *think* will always be the object on which you called `__defineGetter__` (since I can't immediately see a way to transfer that function elsewhere, but I wouldn't *guarantee* you couldn't; you'd have to do it on purpose, though).

It's worth noting that `__defineGetter__` is non-standard and obsolete. The current way to define a getter is to use [`Object.defineProperty`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.6) or [`Object.defineProperties`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.7), like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "foo", {
  get: function() {
    // Here, `this` is the string
    return this.toUpperCase();
  }
});

console.log("hi there".foo);
```

...which logs `"HI THERE"`.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/asinek/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/asinek/1/edit)

Comment: Lightning fast !! Nice example and very detailed, clears all doubts. Thanks for answering. StackOverflow Rocks !!

Comment: @ɟɐɹɐs ןoɯuɐ: LOL! Glad that helped! Best,